# Binding google scripts to gmail

Tags: javascript, gmail, bind

Is there a way to bind google scripts to Gmail? I am trying to get a script to run whenever a certain Gmail account receives an email, and then parse that email based on keywords in the text. However, I cannot find the correct way to trigger this script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't check for incoming messages but you can set a time drive trigger and set it to run every minute to check for new messages.